# How would you call this variable "direct3Ddevice" or "direct3dDevice"?

Tags: naming-conventions

I am following the naming convention rules:

- Mixed case starting with lower case (e.g. `theDevice`)
- Not using multiple capital letters for abbreviations/acronyms (e.g. `XmlDevice` instead of `XMLDevice`) to improve readability.

The issue I am having is whether I should write my variable as `direct3dDevice` or `direct3Ddevice` or `direct3DDevice`.

Argument for `direct3dDevice`

- The '3' could be seen as a capital letter (since it is of similar size) or just as part of an abbreviation, therefore the 'd' after it should be a lowercase letter. Especially since 'Direct3D' is a name.

Argument for `direct3Ddevice`

- The '3' is a number and should not be treated as a capital letter, therefore the first letter afterwards, 'd' should be capitalized. The next 'd' from 'device' should be lowercase since no two capital letters should be after each other.

Argument for `direct3DDevice`

- The '3' is a number and should not be treated as a capital letter, therefore the first letter afterwards, 'd' should be capitalized. The next 'd' from 'device' should be a capital letter to follow the mixed case convention of starting a new word with a capital letter.

Comment: Which language are you using? If you are using a .NET language then the last one is the recommended naming convention, at least according to ReSharper.

Comment: @MoonMoo I'm using C++.

Answer (score 1):

I find

```
direct3dDevice
```

to be the most readable and easier to adopt. You wouldn't have to think twice about which letters must be capitalized and thereby is less prone to naming errors when calling that same variable later on.

The most important part to this type of naming convention is just being consistent.

Or you can adopt a well-known style guide like [Google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Naming).

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I have to agree. I am following a style guide, yet these kinds of specific cases are never really incorporated.